# on javascript using switch syntax function

Tags: javascript, variables, switch-statement, parseint

when i used switch using prompt
the value from prompt is not work in the function
what problem is it ?

there are my code under below

I try `parseInt.prompt`
change value string to the int
but it doesn't work:

```
function solution(){
    
    var month = prompt();
    var month2 = parseInt.month

    switch (month2){
    case 1:
        return 31;
        break;
    
    case 2:
        return 28;
        break;

    case 3:
        return 31;
        break;
    
    case 4:
        return 31;
        break;
    
    default :
        console.log("write month")
        break;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function wrongly

It should be:

```js
var month2 = parseInt(month)
```